# Native Mobile Apps: Server Sent Events and Forever Frame

Tags: android, ios, comet, server-sent-events

I have a web service running on an IIS 7.5. I want to provide push notifications to my clients. I’m considering using SignalR but in order to get rid of a client library dependency I’m also considering using only one of techniques used in SignalR (Websockets, Forever Frame, Server Sent Events).

I know I can’t use Websockets in IIS 7.5 therefore this is not an option at the moment. I think I could use Forever Frame for IE and SSE for the other browsers so I would be good to go for browsers.

My question is regarding native mobile apps: Can I use Forever Frame and/or Server Sent Events in iOS, Android and Windows native apps?

Comment: Please let me know if you want me to provide additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSE is natively supported by Safari, Chrome and Firefox in both desktop and mobile versions.

SSE is not supported natively by IE (but can be emulated with https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource) and it's not supported by Android's built-in crappy "Browser" (that rubbish doesn't support anything...)